# Getting Contact Added date in Android

Tags: android

I have a requirement of getting contact details

When I start service in background. My app has to take has to take all contacts including contact added date.

Please help in this.

Thanks,
Uday

Comment: use `ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTACT_STATUS_TIMESTAMP` and get the milliseconds and convert to date .http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.ContactStatusColumns.html#CONTACT_STATUS_TIMESTAMP

Answer (score 0):

Content providers.

Check this out:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider.html

There's a sample app for that too.